# ActionLink using T4MVC with a block a HTML code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, t4mvc

Is there a way to get this working:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CategoryListByKeywordsDetails)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("ver >", MVC.Ad.ListByCategory(item.Id, (string)ViewBag.keywords))
        {
            <em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SearchCount)</em> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) <span class="float-right">ver ></span>
        }
    </li>
}
```

I want the result (I put spaces to show the HTML code):

```
<a href="/Ad/ListByCategory?categoryId=1&keywords=alfa">
    <em>6</em>Carros
    <span class="float-right">ver &gt;</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with any of the `@Html.ActionLink` overloads. Use `@Url.Action` inside an `a` tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Ad.ListByCategory(item.Id, (string)ViewBag.keywords))">
    <em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SearchCount)</em> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) 
    <span class="float-right">ver &gt;</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is including some HTML codes inside an action link. You could simply use an "a" tag:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryListByKeywordsDetails)
    {
        <li>
          <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Ad.ListByCategory(item.Id, (string)ViewBag.keywords))">                
                    <em>@item.SearchCount</em>@item.Name<span class="float-right">ver &gt;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but your solution writes "<a href="T4MVC_ActionResult">". You need the Url.Action from @Bennor solution to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your comment, yes you're right. Anyway I changed the code based the @Bennor's solution.